# query to select non matching records from two tables

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables like this:

Table Student_Old:

```
id name city
1   A    X
2   B    Y
3   C    Z
```

Table Student_new:

```
id name city
1   A    X
2   M    Y
3   C    K
```

As you can see for Id 2,name is mismatching and for Id 3, city is mismatching in both tables(I am doing comparison on ID which is primary key in both table, basically student_new is backup table for old ). Now I want to get these 2 rows which are not matching.
e.g: 
student_old s1, student_new s2-

```
s1.id  s2.id s1.name s2.name s1.city s2.city
  2      2       B      M      X       X
  3      3       C      C      Z       K
```

Comment: Hint:  `inner join`.

Comment: What's the expected result if you add the row (4, F, G) to student_old?

Comment: In that case I will not have this record in student_new, and i am doing comparison on Id, so student_new will not have Id 4. I am not bothering for records which are not present in one of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't care about records which are in one table but not in the other, a simple JOIN will suffice:

```
SELECT s1.id AS old_id, s2.id AS new_id,
       s1.name AS old_name, s2.name AS new_name,
       s1.city AS old_city, s2.city AS new_city
FROM student_old s1
JOIN student_new s2
ON s1.id = s2.id
WHERE s1.name != s2.name OR s1.city != s2.city
```

Output:

```
old_id  new_id  old_name    new_name    old_city    new_city
2       2       B           M           Y           Y
3       3       C           C           Z           K
```

Comment: "I am not bothering for records which are not present in one of the tablel"

Comment: @jarlh Sheesh! that was in a comment **after** I posted!

Comment: True, but I raised the question before you posted!

Comment: @jarlh, you did indeed. I decided to play safe with the answer but have now corrected it based on that comment. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: @jarlh : thanks for bringing that point, which helped me to get desired solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use inner join and where clause do filter out non matching name and city

```
select a.* , b.* from Student_Old inner join Student_new
on a.id=b.id
where a.name<>b.name or a.city<>b.city
```

Answer (score 0):

use join

```
select os.*,ns.* Student_Old os join Student_new ns on os.id=ns.id 
where os.city!=ns.city OR os.name!=ns.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT so.id AS id_1, so.name AS name_1, so.city AS city_1,
sn.id AS id_2, sn.name AS name_2, sn.city AS city_2
FROM student_old so
INNER JOIN student_new sn
ON so.id = sn.id
WHERE so.name <> sn.name AND so.city <> sn.city
```